# ObjectForKey method is not saving the value

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to store some values to use them but I'm writing this code and in the console are the values printed but when i try to assign that value to dateComp.day it returns nil, and I don't know why,is nil do you have idea why this is happening thanks in advance.

```
 for item in medicineArray {
            let obj = item as NSDictionary
            for (key, value) in obj {
                print("Property: \"\(key as! String)\"")


                dateComp.day = obj.object(forKey: ["day"]) as? Int
                dateComp.hour = obj.object(forKey: "time") as? Int
                print("componentes\(String(describing: dateComp.day))")
                print("componente2\(String(describing: dateComp.minute))")


            }
```

Comment: why still using `NSDictionary` in swift?

Comment: I just copy and paste the recommended solution, but... well it works also. Do you have any idea why that properties return nil?

Comment: Why are you using `obj.object(forKey: ["day"])` ? Use `dateComp.day = obj["day"] as? Int`

Comment: check that your values are Ints and not another type

Comment: Since you are using `NSDictionary` there is a good chance that your values are `NSNumber` or perhaps even a `NSString` - check.

Comment: add `debugPrint(obj.object(forKey: "day"))` and `debugPrint(obj.object(forKey: "time"))`and post what the console prints

Comment: Both are strings but the dateComp.day just accept Int, but I need it because I'm using the calendar and that´s the property, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why do yo use key array `["day"]` instead of key `"day"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    for item in medicineArray {
        let obj = item as NSDictionary

        if let dayInt = Int(obj["day"]){
            dateComp.day = dayInt
        }

        if let hourInt = Int(obj["time"]){
            dateComp.hour = hourInt
        }

    }
```